# Randomly playing multiple instances of movieclip AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, instance, movieclip

I have made a movieclip of an eye, which is set to play a blinking animation at random intervals. 
I want to place many instances of that movieclip on the stage, where they're all being played at different times. 
But if I put multiple instances of the clip on the stage, only one will play. How do I have many instances playing at the same time?

I haven't used flash for years so please explain simply if you can~

```
stop();
var eyeTimer = new Timer(1000 + Math.random() * 1000);
eyeTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, blink);
eyeTimer.start();
function blink(evt:TimerEvent):void {
  Timer(evt.currentTarget).delay = 1000 + Math.random() * 1000;

 trace( "triggered!" );
 eye.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Comment: You need to approach to this eye as to a component. Transfer this code **into** the eye so it would work by itself. Then you'll have no problem putting as many eyes as you want.

Comment: Okay so I did that and now it says 'call to possibly undefined method 'eye', and also every eye is blinking at the same time not randomly.

Comment: That's exactly why I didn't say *copy*, I said *transfer*. That means you should understand what you are doing and the fact you are addressing the eye **MovieClip** from the inside, not outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easier to use setTimeOut method. user below code for your Eye MovieClip

```
addEye (45,78);
addEye (76,44);
...

function addEye (X,Y)
{
    var eye:Eye = new Eye ();
    eye.x = X;
    eye.y = Y;
    this.addChild(eye);

    eye.gotoAndStop(1);//Stop the eye from blinking. may be on frame 1 maye be on other frame number.
    setTimeOut(blink,1000+Math.random()*1000);
    function blink():void
    {
        eye.gotoAndPlay(2);
        setTimeOut(blink,1000+Math.random()*1000);//Call the random function with random time again
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the original code worked better for more randomized blinking. However, I still get the same error, 'call to possibly undefined method eye' and every eye is blinking simultaneously.

Comment: All eyes are blinking in the same time because no code are activated for them and the default play back is making them blink at the same time. where do you write your code on them? you should add your code to the first frame of your Eye MovieClip or the Eye MovieClip base class. and you have to switch eye.gotoAndPlay(1) with this.gotoAndPlay(1) then.

Comment: The code is on the first frame of the eye movieclip. I don't have a base class though.

Comment: So, you do you have "eye" instance name there? if not, change the eye.gotoAndStop to this.gotoAndStop. I think you forgot to change the name after moving your code to the Eye MovieClip.

Comment: With your advice, I have done this. 

`this.gotoAndStop(1);
var eye:Eye = new Eye();
var eyeTimer = new Timer(1000 + Math.random() * 1000);

eyeTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, blink);
eyeTimer.start();
function blink(evt:TimerEvent):void {
  Timer(evt.currentTarget).delay = 1000 + Math.random() * 1000;

 trace( "triggered!" );
this.gotoAndPlay(1);
eyeTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, blink);
}`

I had to add the removeEventListener because Flash would crash otherwise. I think it was infinitely loading it or something. But I don't know how to restart it?

Comment: I edit my answer. Make copies of your eyes with codes nested in the addEye function to make the eyes blink separately. (You have to handle removeListner s or removeTimeOutss by your self.)